# Create instance of generic type using Activator and then assign the new object to a property causing problems, TargetException

Tags: c#, reflection

Im currently using the Activator (Activator.CreateInstance(myType)) to generate an object based on the type of a property.. basically something like this:

```
var x = Activator.CreateInstance(myProperty.PropertyType)
```

The property is a generic type,
Later on I also create an instance of the class where this property is located and assign the value of x to the target property.
By simply doing this:

```
targetProperty.SetValue(model,x);
```

The thing is that I for some reason get a different type with the Activator than the targetProperty is.. in this case my targetProperty is of the type: `{UDev.Framework.Models.Definitions.UDevProperty`1[System.String] Firstname}`
and x in this case is of the type:

```
{UDev.Framework.Models.Definitions.UDevProperty<string>}
```

the model is of the following class:

```
public class DummyModel
    {
        public UDevProperty<string> Firstname { get; set; }
    }
```

And to make the problem even more clear.. as you see above.. the actual type of the property Firstname is UDevProperty, and the "generated" x-object is also of the type `UDevProperty<string>`, however.. it seems like once I try to assign x to the Firstname-property, it expects an object of the type :`{UDev.Framework.Models.Definitions.UDevProperty`1[System.String] Firstname}`
Any ideas of how to fix this?
Im sort of clue-less why the activator generates a type that doesnt match the targetproperty's-type..

Comment: Seems to have been an issue with the fact that the x-object in this case was created in another static function in a different class than where I assigned it back to my property..

Comment: Is this just a simple typo as you have `myProperty` in the `CreateInstance` line and `targetProperty` in the `SetValue` line? Have you mixed up your variables?